# Rails 7: onclick javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I need some help with the issue bellow...

This is the setup I have: Rails 7.0.5, ruby 3.0.0p0.

I have installed bootstrap 5.

Also I have installed jQuery and jQuery-ui according to this https://gorails.com/episodes/how-to-use-jquery-with-esbuild. I've tested it and everything seems to work just fine without any errors in the console.

Now I'm trying to implement a simple onclick like this one: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_overlay

And when I put this:

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

Inside my application.js file and I click on `<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>`... it gives me this error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: openNav`.

But when I put the javascript above inside the html view page everything works just fine. The weird part is that I have other code(javascript, jQuery) inside the application.js file and all of it works just fine.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to use these functions you have to assign them to the window.

Like:

```
window.openNav = function () {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

window.closeNav = function () {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

Not sure why, but this is what I've had to do for my globally declared functions being compiled into `application.js` by esbuild.  I assume the reason why you can run your javascript inside of the html view is because it can reach the definition whereas there is something wrong with the way esbuild is compiling your functions for application-wide usage.  The solution above may only be a patch, there could be a better solution out there.